# How does bundle clean fit into CircleCI cache?

Tags: circleci, circleci-2.0

The CircleCI docs include some information on why `bundle clean` should be run when cache is involved, but I'm having a hard time understanding how. I'm confused about the code block in the `Bundler (Ruby)` section here:
https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/caching/#bundler-ruby

The code block in question is:

```
- run: bundle install & bundle clean
- restore_cache:
    keys:
      # when lock file changes, use increasingly general patterns to restore cache
      - v1-gem-cache-{{ arch }}-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}
      - v1-gem-cache-{{ arch }}-{{ .Branch }}-
      - v1-gem-cache-{{ arch }}-
- save_cache:
    paths:
      - ~/.bundle
    key: v1-gem-cache-{{ arch }}-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}
```

I'm reading this process as:

- Run `bundle install` *before* the cache is put in place (a full gem installation time before restoring cache, which negates the time-saving benefits of a cache) and then run `bundle clean`
- Restore the cache over the installed gems
- Don't do *anything* (between `restore_cache` and `save_cache` steps)
- Save the new cache

Am I understanding that process correctly?

This looks to me like `restore_cache` and `save_cache` steps are not going to be effective, because the full `bundle install` time would have already been spent.

If I'm understanding things, would this be a more effective process?

```
- restore_cache:
    keys:
      # when lock file changes, use increasingly general patterns to restore cache
      - v1-gem-cache-{{ arch }}-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}
      - v1-gem-cache-{{ arch }}-{{ .Branch }}-
      - v1-gem-cache-{{ arch }}-
- run: bundle install & bundle clean
- save_cache:
    paths:
      - ~/.bundle
    key: v1-gem-cache-{{ arch }}-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}
```

If I'm not understanding this correctly, can anyone help clarify how the suggested code block works?

**Update:**
It also looks like

```
- run: bundle install & bundle clean
```

needs to be modified to

```
- run: bundle install && bundle clean
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you are correct and that this is a typo in the CircleCI Docs. I've opened a PR to fix: https://github.com/circleci/circleci-docs/pull/2663